# How can I mapreduce a object with complex subdocuments that relate to each other

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hadoop, mongoose

Firstly this may be a misguided question and if that's the case I would appreciate some guidance as to how I should proceed.

From what I have found online it seems like the mongodb/mongoose mapReduce is the best way to do this but I have been trying to wrap my head around the it and I am struggling to understand it for anything that's not trivial, I am wondering if someone could help explain in terms of my problem. I am not necessarily looking for a full solution. I would actually appreciate pseudo code that well explained. I think what confusing me in particular is how to deal with aggregating and combining 2 or more sets subdocuments.

Also I know that this might be down to a bad model/collection design but unfortunately that is completely out of my hands so please do not suggest remodeling.

My particular issue is We have an existing model that looks something like the following:

```
survey: {
            _id: 1111,
            name: "name",
            questions: [
                {_id: 1, text: "a,b, or c?", type: "multipleChoice", options: [a, b, c,]},
                {_id: 2, text: "what do you think", type: "freeform"}
            ],
            participants: [{_id: 1, name: "user 1"}, {_id: 2, name: "user 2"}],
            results: [{_id: 123, userId: 1, questionId: 1, answer: "a"},
                {_id: 124, userId: 2, questionId: 1, answer: "b"},
                {_id: 125, userId: 1, questionId: 2, answer: "this is some answer"},
                {_id: 126, userId: 2, questionId: 2, answer: "this is another answer"}]

        }
```

and we then have another model that was developed separately that was used to track users the progress of the user throughout the survey (this is only a basic subset, we also track different events)

```
trackings:{
    _id:123,
    surveyId: 1,
    userId: 123,
    starttime: "2015-05-13 10:46:20.347Z"
    endtime: "2015-05-13 10:59:20.347Z"
}
```

what I would like to do somehow is get something like:

```
{
    survey: "survey name",
    _id : 1,
    totalAverageTime: "00:23:00",
    fastestTime : "00:23:00",
    slowestTime: "00:25:00",
    questions: [
    {
       _id: 1, text: "a,b, or c?", 
       type: "multipleChoice", 
       mostPopularAnswer: "a", 
       averageTime: "00:13:00", 
       anwers : [{ userId: 1, answer: "a", time:"00:14:00"},
                { userId: 2, answer: "a", time:"00:12:00"}]

    },{
        _id: 2, text:"what do you think",
        type:"freeform",
        averageTime : "00:10:00",
        answers : [{ userId: 1, answer: "this is some answer", time:"00:11:00"},
                { userId: 2, answer: "this is another answer", time:"00:09:00"}]


    }

  ]

}
```

Comment: I've got a solution in mind which involves creating another output collection that joins the two schemas and then uses the aggregation framework to calculate the desired aggregation. However, it would be really helpful if you could specify the MongoDB version in use since that will affect the aggregation operation as it requires using some operators that are found in later versions.

Comment: We are currently using mongodb 3.8 and mongoose 4

Comment: Was that a typo, mongodb 3.8?

Comment: Sorry yes meant to be mongodb 3

Comment: actually to be more accurate we ae currently on 2.6.5 but upgrading to 3 in the next few weeks

Comment: How do you track the time for answering? I've got a solution at hand but now stuck at aggregating the time for answers.

Comment: so the time is actually just the difference between the start time and the end time, the averages, fastest and slowest times for a survey are based on the sum of the time spent on each of the questions for each user (this is obtained from the tracking collection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach uses the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** to come up with a solution that is closer to the desired output. This is dependant on a third collection which can be seen as a merge between the two collections `survey` and `trackings`.

First and foremost, suppose you have the following collections with the test documents based on the example in your question:

```
// survey collection
db.survey.insert({
    _id: 1111,
    name: "name",
    questions: [
        {_id: 1, text: "a,b, or c?", type: "multipleChoice", options: ["a", "b", "c",]},
        {_id: 2, text: "what do you think", type: "freeform"}
    ],
    participants: [{_id: 1, name: "user 1"}, {_id: 2, name: "user 2"}],
    results: [{_id: 123, userId: 1, questionId: 1, answer: "a"},
        {_id: 124, userId: 2, questionId: 1, answer: "b"},
        {_id: 125, userId: 1, questionId: 2, answer: "this is some answer"},
        {_id: 126, userId: 2, questionId: 2, answer: "this is another answer"}]

})

// trackings collection
db.trackings.insert([
    {
        _id:1,
        surveyId: 1111,
        userId: 1,
        starttime: "2015-05-13 10:46:20.347Z",
        endtime: "2015-05-13 10:59:20.347Z"
    },
    {
        _id:2,
        surveyId: 1111,
        userId: 2,
        starttime: "2015-05-13 10:13:06.176Z",
        endtime: "2015-05-13 10:46:28.176Z"
    }    
])
```

To create the third collection (lets call it `output_collection`), you would need to iterate over the `trackings` collection using the [**`find()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find) cursor's [**`forEach()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach) method, convert the fields with the date strings to actual ISODate objects, create an array field that stores the `survey` result and then save the merged object into the third collection. The following demonstrates this operation:

```
db.trackings.find().forEach(function(doc){
    var survey = db.survey.find({"_id": doc.surveyId}).toArray();
    doc.survey = survey;
    doc["starttime"] = ISODate(doc.starttime);
    doc["endtime"] = ISODate(doc.endtime);
    db.output_collection.save(doc);
});
```

After merging the two collections into output_collection, querying it with `db.output_collection.findOne()` will yield:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "surveyId" : 1111,
    "userId" : 1,
    "starttime" : ISODate("2015-05-13T10:46:20.347Z"),
    "endtime" : ISODate("2015-05-13T10:59:20.347Z"),
    "survey" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1111,
            "name" : "name",
            "questions" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "text" : "a,b, or c?",
                    "type" : "multipleChoice",
                    "options" : [ 
                        "a", 
                        "b", 
                        "c"
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "text" : "what do you think",
                    "type" : "freeform"
                }
            ],
            "participants" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "name" : "user 1"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "name" : "user 2"
                }
            ],
            "results" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : 123,
                    "userId" : 1,
                    "questionId" : 1,
                    "answer" : "a"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 124,
                    "userId" : 2,
                    "questionId" : 1,
                    "answer" : "b"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 125,
                    "userId" : 1,
                    "questionId" : 2,
                    "answer" : "this is some answer"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 126,
                    "userId" : 2,
                    "questionId" : 2,
                    "answer" : "this is another answer"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can then apply the aggregation on this collection. The aggregation pipeline should consist of four `$unwind`** operator stages which deconstruct the arrays from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document replaces the array with an element value.

The next [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) operator stage reshapes each document in the stream, such as by adding a new field `duration` which calculates the time difference in minutes between the starttime and endtime date fields, and uses the **[Arithmetic Operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#arithmetic-operators)** to do the calculation.

After this is the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator pipeline stage which groups input documents by the `"survey"` key and applies the **[accumulator expression(s)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#accumulators)** to each group. Consumes all input documents and outputs one document per each distinct group.

So your aggregation pipeline should be something like this:

```
db.output_collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$survey" },
    { "$unwind": "$survey.questions" },
    { "$unwind": "$survey.participants" },
    { "$unwind": "$survey.results" },
    {
        "$project": {
            "survey": 1,
            "surveyId": 1,
            "userId": 1,
            "starttime": 1,
            "endtime": 1,
            "duration": {
                "$divide": [
                    { "$subtract": [ "$endtime", "$starttime" ] },
                    1000 * 60
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$surveyId",
            "survey": { "$first": "$survey.name"},
            "totalAverageTime": {
                "$avg": "$duration"
            },
            "fastestTime": {
                "$min": "$duration"
            },
            "slowestTime": {
                "$max": "$duration"
            },
            "questions": {
                "$addToSet": "$survey.questions"
            },
            "answers": {
                "$addToSet": "$survey.results"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$out": "survey_results"
    }
])
```

`db.survey_results.find()` **Output**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1111,
            "survey" : "name",
            "totalAverageTime" : 23.18333333333334,
            "fastestTime" : 13,
            "slowestTime" : 33.36666666666667,
            "questions" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "text" : "what do you think",
                    "type" : "freeform"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "text" : "a,b, or c?",
                    "type" : "multipleChoice",
                    "options" : [ 
                        "a", 
                        "b", 
                        "c"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "answers" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : 126,
                    "userId" : 2,
                    "questionId" : 2,
                    "answer" : "this is another answer"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 124,
                    "userId" : 2,
                    "questionId" : 1,
                    "answer" : "b"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 125,
                    "userId" : 1,
                    "questionId" : 2,
                    "answer" : "this is some answer"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 123,
                    "userId" : 1,
                    "questionId" : 1,
                    "answer" : "a"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Upon getting the aggregation output to another collection, say `survey_results` via the [**`$out`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out) aggregation pipeline, you could then apply some native JavaScript functions together with the [**`find()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find) cursor's [**`forEach()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach) method to get the final object:

```
db.survey_results.find().forEach(function(doc){
    var questions = [];
    doc.questions.forEach(function(q){
       var answers = [];
       doc.answers.forEach(function(a){
            if(a.questionId === q._id){
                delete a.questionId;
                answers.push(a);
            }
       });
       q.answers = answers;
       questions.push(q);
    });       

    delete doc.answers;        
    doc.questions = questions;
    db.survey_results.save(doc);
});
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : 1111,
    "survey" : "name",
    "totalAverageTime" : 23.18333333333334,
    "fastestTime" : 13,
    "slowestTime" : 33.36666666666667,
    "questions" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "text" : "what do you think",
            "type" : "freeform",
            "answers" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : 126,
                    "userId" : 2,
                    "answer" : "this is another answer"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 125,
                    "userId" : 1,
                    "answer" : "this is some answer"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "text" : "a,b, or c?",
            "type" : "multipleChoice",
            "options" : [ 
                "a", 
                "b", 
                "c"
            ],
            "answers" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : 124,
                    "userId" : 2,
                    "answer" : "b"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 123,
                    "userId" : 1,
                    "answer" : "a"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: this is a fantastic, I really appreciate the detail. one question. if I wanted to put the all the answers to each question within the question subdoc would this be possible within the query above our would this take another query on the output?

Comment: @jonnie Yes, quite possible indeed. Just didn't have enough time to finish the aggregation pipeline that produces the exact desired output like the one where you can have the answers as subdocuments in the questions array. Will try to update the answer once I get enough time. But the grand idea is to have another **`$group`** pipeline stage that uses the **`$addToSet`** operator to add elements to an array.

Comment: @jonnie I've updated the answer to include an extra step that can lead you to the final desired result.